# android adapterView addheaderView

Tags: android, android-adapterview

I'm trying to make (for learning purposes) my own implementation of a simple `AdapterView`. Now I have a question: How to add a `headerView` in my custom `adapterView` like `addHeaderView` in `listView`?

I have realized the waterfall part by using `adapterView`, but the header I have has special demands: it can slide horizontally and the whole view as below can slide up and down. I never wrote waterfall as below, but write single lines in `listView`, I can use `addHeaderview` method to add a viewpager in `listView` to meet the demands, but I can't understand how to do it in `adapterView`.

Because I'm a freshman, I can't upload pictures, but you can look at pinterest. I just want to replace the header part aboved waterfall part with a viewpager.

Comment: Have a look at the source code of `ListView`.

Comment: And have a look at your interpunction characters, try using the normal ones next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand you are looking for.

ListView is a control have a part that is the header, wich you can customize setting a custom view with addHeaderViewMethod.

AdapterView defines a control that is used to display data with a custom style or information distribution (in a ListActivity for example)

I guess your header is the activity header. I hope to help you.

**UPDATED:**

Ok, you must follow these steps:

1 - You are extending AdapterView. Define a method class like AddHeaderView (like ListView) for adding required header views

2 - Create a ViewPager wrapper. This class must wrap ViewPager control that you are using with AdapterView (required for horizontal slide)

3 - On setAdapter method implementation, you must check if header views was added, then the adapter passed to this method must be wrapped by your ViewPager wrapper.

I highly recomend you that take a look into source code from [ListView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ListView.java) and [HeaderViewListAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java#HeaderViewListAdapter). This is the way to get what you want.

Comment: I want to write a waterfall view like pinterest feedlist， I know write a view extends adapterView can do it； but I have a special demand： I have add a view ，this view like viewpager ， it can horizontal slide. I add use addHeaderView method to add this viewpager in listView earlier，but I don't know how to do this in adapterView！the demo I want to finish， I show you as upper